# Using the standard WordPress "New User" interface on a multisite

Tags: multisite, user-registration

We've set up a WordPress multisite with the intention of adding users manually via the Dashboard. However, it looks like the Multisite "Add User" menu is lacking several features, and this is causing us issues. For example, a WordPress multisite:

- Doesn't add users until they confirm, meaning that they can't be displayed elsewhere in the site.
- Shows a user their password in plain text once they register, rather than prompting them to set their password like regular WordPress.
- Doesn't allow anything other than lowercase letters in the username.

For reference, [here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJpfa.png) of the regular WordPress "Add User" menu, and [here's one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5juz.png) of the Multisite equivalent.

My question is, is it possible to force a WordPress Multisite to use the regular Add User/Registration process?